# UITableview scrollToRow function error when view is added to tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll, addsubview

I added a view to tableView by using `addSubview`

```
   let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 52, y: ypos + 25, width: self.view.frame.width - 52, height: 1.5))
    timeIndicatorView = view
    self.eventCatalogTableView.addSubview(timeIndicatorView)
```

and then I use `scrollToRow` function on the tableView to scroll to the current Time.

```
func rollToCurrentTime() {
    eventCatalogTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date()), section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: false)
}
```

Everything works normally when I scroll to the row where the added view cannot be seen. Like this

[image]

However, when I scroll to the row where the added view is showed, the position of the view changes to a weird random position like this
 [image]

In this case, when I scroll all the way up to the top and then scroll down, the view gets positioned in the right spot. 
Is this an internal bug or is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Why are you adding the indicator to the tableView? You should be adding it to the relevant cell.

Comment: is it not appropriate to add to the tableView?

Comment: If the time listed in the tableView are all inside cells. This this line should be added to the appropriate cell where your time is. And you'll do a bit of math to calculate the position of the line inside the cell (Split the area height into 60)

Comment: but when I'm adding the label the label cannot stay in one cell when the time is between the two cell..

Comment: in between two cells will still be inside one cell right? If the time is 9:40, it will be inside the 9 cell right?

Comment: but the height of the label is like 20ish and the height of the cell is 50 so it can't stay in one cell all the time

Comment: Errr one cell has only 1 label right?

Comment: @SeongMinChoo why don't you add the timeIndicatorView to be on top of the tableview...so addSubview(timeIndicatorView) instead of self.eventCatalogTableView.addSubview(timeIndicatorView)

Comment: if I put it on top of the tableView it won't scroll with the tableView. And next to the label and yes one cell has only 1 label